# How to count distinct values from a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table structure as follows :

```
ID            USER              STATE
---           ---               ---
1             U1                CA 
2             U1                VA
3             U2                CT
4             U3                AZ
5             U2                CT
```

The query is expected to take all the users and count the states they have visited to, and to print users who have visited more than or equal to 1 state.

I am trying to basically make a query to give me this output :

```
U1    2
```

Any ideas on how this query can be structured?

I have tried the following, and I am getting stuck with this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(STATE) AS ST , USER 
FROM TEMP_TABLE) 
WHERE count(STATE) > 1;
```

Comment: @KenWhite - i was editing my question after my first post, and your comment came in. I understand those points you mentioned. I have made the necessary ammends (you caught it as I was editing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the HAVING clause is intended for: filtering data on your aggregation.

```
SELECT user
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT state)
  FROM temp_table
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT state) > 1;
```

If the HAVING clause makes you uncomfortable, then you could do this nesting queries as you showed, with just a small tweak.

```
SELECT user
  FROM (SELECT user
              ,COUNT(DISTINCT state) AS state_cnt
          FROM temp_table
         GROUP BY user) t
 WHERE state_cnt > 1;
```

In either case, you group by user and count states to get the answer of "states per user."